# Is "Exists there an alternative to PHP?" considered "old English"?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, old-english, do-support

I like this way:

> Exists there an alternative to PHP?

But there's also:

> Is there an alternative to PHP?

And:

> Does it exist an alternative to PHP?

Or maybe:

> Does there exist an alternative to PHP?

I have a vague feeling that the first one sounds like English grammar from "old times" (hundreds of years ago). Is this wrong? Is it perfectly "acceptable"? Would it confuse anyone? Does it make it sound like the person is not a native English-speaker?

Answer (score 4):

As @StuartF said in a comment to your question, there's no Old English (pre 1066) anywhere in these sentences ;)

> Exists there an alternative to PHP?

Here it's the use of *exists* that strikes me as flowery and poetic. And it may indeed feel archaic.

> Is there an alternative to PHP?

Totally fine, probably the most common way to phrase this question.

> Does it exist an alternative to PHP?

Ungrammatical, do not use this version. Playing with word order and / or punctuation it is salvageable ("An alternative? Does it exits?") but that would be very context-specific.

> Does there exist an alternative to PHP?

Grammatically that is fine, but it emphasizes some feeling of incredulity. As if you do not think there *is* such an alternative. It feels like you left out some emphasis: "Does there even exist an alternative to PHP?", in which case the stress would be on *exist*.

If you change the order a little bit, you avoid this connotation, as in @SlowlySwift's comment:

> Does an alternative to PHP exist?

This is absolutely fine, although I think it still emphasizes a bit more doubt than "is there an alternative?"

In short, if the verb *be* works, use it.

*Exist* can have extra connotations, depending on context.

Off-topic afterthought: I won't get into a philosophical discussion here, but for existentialist thinkers, *being* is quite a different concept to *existing*.

Comment: @Henry Because I discussed the options in the question, not the comments. The alternative you mention wasn't Stuart's, by the way ;) I will add it anyway, I hadn't noticed it.